# Yii2 Basic - How can I call a view to be display inside tab

Tags: gridview, yii2, tabs, php-7

I hope someone can help me to solve this.
In my view I'm applying TabsX::widget hope that later I can display the view inside the each tab. Below is the code for the tabs display in view:

```
<?= TabsX::widget(
                        [
                            'items'=>[
                                 [
                                    'label'=>'<i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home',
                                    'content'=>'$content1',
                                    'active'=>true
                                ],
                                [
                                    'label'=>'<i class="fas fa-user"></i> Profile',
                                    'content'=>'$content2',
                                    // 'linkOptions'=>['data-url'=>\yii\helpers\Url::to(['/site/tabs-data'])]
                                ],
                                [
                                    'label'=>'<i class="fas fa-list-alt"></i> Menu',
                                    'items'=>[
                                         [
                                             'label'=>'Option 1',
                                             'encode'=>false,
                                             'content'=>'$content3',
                                         ],
                                         [
                                             'label'=>'Option 2',
                                             'encode'=>false,
                                             'content'=>'$content4',
                                         ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                            'position'=>TabsX::POS_ABOVE,
                            'encodeLabels'=>false
                        ]
                    ) ?>
```

Now... how can I replace the 'content'=>'$content' for each of the tab so that it will display the grid-view that I already create. Different tab may have different grid-view or other view.

here is the grid-view code :

```
<div class="vehicle-view">
     <h2 class="page-header">View Vehicle # ID : <?php echo $model->Vehicle_ID; ?></h2>

                        <?= DetailView::widget([
                            'model' => $model,
                            'attributes' => [
                                'Vehicle_ID',
                                'Station_Code',
                                'Plate_No',
                                'Owner',
                                'Company_Name',
                                'Vehicle_Brand',
                                'Vehicle_Model',
                                'Vehicle_Color',
                                'Vehicle_Length',
                                'Vehicle_Width',
                                'Vehicle_Capacity',
                            ],
                        ]) ?>
```

How can I display the Grid-view inside the tab? Help me please...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`renderPartial()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-controller#renderPartial()-detail) easily. just where you have `'content'=>'$content'` change it to:

```
'content'=> Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial("@frontend/views/tabs/mytab")
```

ps. You know you can change `@frontend/views/tabs/mytab` to address of your view you want to show.

Comment: No need to call it in that complicated way. In view templates you can do `$this->render("@frontend/views/tabs/mytab")` with exactly same result. Controller's `renderPartial` method is just a wrapper of this method designed for use inside of controller if you need to render the view without layout.

Comment: @MichalHynčica see document of `yii2` and you can see diffrences. if you just do `render` your assets will loaded again with your template.

Comment: They won't load again. In view template `$this->render()` doesn't call the controller's `render` method but `yii\base\View::render()`. That's exactly what [`yii\base\Controller::renderPartial`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Controller.php#L415) does.
It's also described in article about views here [https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-views#rendering-in-views](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-views#rendering-in-views).

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to load them in the `main` `controller` where you call the `action` that loads the tabs `view`using the `renderAjax()` method.

This method loads the content as a render (With all the assets needed) but without the layout.

So at the end the action would look like:

```
public function actionTabs(){

      $tab1 = $this->renderAjax('tab1');
      $tab2 = $this->renderAjax('tab2');
      $tab3 = $this->renderAjax('tab3');

      return $this->render('tabs', [ 
        'tab1' => $tab1, 
        'tab2' => $tab2, 
        'tab3' => $tab3 
      ]
}
```